# The defective doyle

Tags: number-theory, puzzle

There are six cans each containing doyles(each doyle weighs a gram), out them any of them can be defective. How can we find the defective cans in one weighing? and if each can has only two dozen doyles how can we find the defective can in one weighing? I cannot under stand the solution provided in the book for the first question.

PS: This question is from the book mathematical puzzle tales by Martin Gardner.

Comment: You should provide the solution from the book for those of us who don't have it at our fingertips or haven't read it or have read it but don't have perfect memories. :-)

Comment: How many doyles per can are there in the first question? (And, just  out of curiosity: what is a doyle?)

Comment: What's the difference between a defective doyle and a non-defective doyle?

Comment: Six cans, each containing miniature clones of Sir Arthur Conan Doyle.

Comment: In the first case, it was unspecified how many cans were defective.  So they needed a general answer which could identify one or all cans.  In the second case, they specified that no more than 2 cans were defective, as well as fewer / can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the actual puzzle, each can contains $100$ doyles, and within a single can, either all the doyles are good or all are defective. Defective doyles always weigh exactly $1.001$g. To identify which cans contain defective doyles, weigh together $63$ doyles as follows: $1$ doyle from the first can, $2$ from the second can, $4$ from the third can, $8$ from the fourth can, $16$ from the fifth can, and $32$ from the sixth can. If the total weight is over $63$ grams, there are some defective doyles. If the ***excess*** weight is at least $32$ milligrams, the sixth can must contain defective doyles, because there aren't enough doyles being weighed from all the other cans together to create that much excess. If so, subtract $32$ from the excess weight. If the excess weight (after possibly subtracting 32 in the last step) now exceeds $16$, the fifth can contains defective doyles. If it does, subtract $16$ from the excess weight. And so on.

In the second part of the problem, no can contains $32$ doyles, so this strategy is impossible. (You didn't ask about that, so I won't say more.)

Comment: Exactly.  By using exponents of two, you can find the overage in milligrams and only one combination would provide that particular overage amount.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Steve Kass's answer, if each can has only $24$ doyles, take $11$, $17$, $20$, $22$, $23$, and $24$ doyles from cans $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, and $6$ respectively and put them on the scale. Notice that no two subsets of $\{11,17,20,22,23,24\}$ have the same sum. Hence, the excess weight in milligrams uniquely determines the subset of the cans which contain defective doyles.

Comment: Nice! In case anyone wonders where Jimmy’s strange set of numbers comes from (I did), see this entry in OEIS: http://oeis.org/A096858